# Change colour of UImage from firebase to black and white

Tags: firebase, swift3, uiimage, xcode8, firebase-storage

Is it possible to load an image from firebase using a url and then changing it's color to black and white? 
If I used an image from assets it works but I'm loading my images from firebase via a url and when I try to apply the code below backgroundProfileImage.image equals nil or an Image is not detected. Im also using SDWebImage load my images if that helps. How can I make this work? I Appreciate the help in advance. Thanks

```
func ChangeImageColor(){
      //Auto Adjustment to Input Image
        var inputImage = CIImage(image: self.backgroundProfileImage.image!) //backgroundProfileImage is not 
        let options:[String : AnyObject] = [CIDetectorImageOrientation:1 as AnyObject]
        let filters = inputImage!.autoAdjustmentFilters(options: options)

        for filter: CIFilter in filters {
            filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            inputImage =  filter.outputImage
        }
        let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(inputImage!, from: inputImage!.extent)
        self.backgroundProfileImage.image =  UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)

        //Apply noir Filter
        let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectTonal")
        currentFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        let output = currentFilter!.outputImage
       // let cgimg = self.context.createCGImage(output!, from: output!.extent)
        let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
        self.backgroundProfileImage.image = processedImage
           }
        })
    }
```

This is how I'm retrieving the image

```
self.backgroundProfileImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: backgroundProfileImageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "empty-profile-3.png"))
```

Ok this method works for me

```
 func ChangeImageColor(){

   let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")
        currentFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: self.backgroundProfileImage.image!), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let output = currentFilter!.outputImage
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output!,from: output!.extent)
        let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
        self.backgroundProfileImage.image = processedImage
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:url), completed: { (image, error, type, url) in
     //Do any thing with image here.
     self.ChangeImageColor(image)
 })


func ChangeImageColor(_ image: UIImage){
  //Auto Adjustment to Input Image
    var inputImage = CIImage(image: image)  
    let options:[String : AnyObject] = [CIDetectorImageOrientation:1 as AnyObject]
    let filters = inputImage!.autoAdjustmentFilters(options: options)

    for filter: CIFilter in filters {
        filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        inputImage =  filter.outputImage
    }
    let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(inputImage!, from: inputImage!.extent)
    self.backgroundProfileImage.image =  UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)

    //Apply noir Filter
    let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectTonal")
    currentFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let output = currentFilter!.outputImage
   // let cgimg = self.context.createCGImage(output!, from: output!.extent)
    let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
    self.backgroundProfileImage.image = processedImage
       }
    })
}
```

Call the method when you retrieve the image with your library and pass it as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated my code to show you how I'm retrieving my image. The issue is I can't pass it as a UIImage because its a string value. I tried passing backgroundProfileImage.image once I've loaded the image from firebase but it passes as nil

Comment: You can use the SDWebImage method downloadImage(with url: URL) that return the image ;)

Comment: Yes I am currently using SdWebImage. The updated code is using the SdWebImage method but some reason once backgroundProfileImage is loaded it is equal to nil when I try pass as an image

Comment: I have seen that SDWebImage has a completion in the same method you are using that retrieve you the image, for the rest I think that your image is nil because you have to init your imageView with the image to retrieve it back

Comment: Ok I don't fully understand what your saying but how would I do what your saying?

Comment: I have edited my answer ;) I think that your imageView.image is nil because the image view need to be initiated with the image.

Comment: ok now its passing the image but the method i'm using is not changing the colour to black and white. Do you having suggestions on how I could change the my image colour to black and white?

Comment: You have set your filter name as CIPhotoEffectTonal try replacing with CIPhotoEffectNoir

Comment: ok now it works. I also changed the method to suiting what you had suggested. Thank you very much for your help!